# Using ASP.NET as application server / WebService, not API or Views

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have worked a bit with `ASP.NET` developing a `Web-API` with controllers etc. but now I am at a point, where I want to split the work.

The *first* application is the Client-App, where the `Web-API` is being called and the retrieved data is being displayed. This application is irrelevant for the question itself, just for better understanding.

The *second* application is only responsible for **making** database **content accessible**, in my case a Web-API.

The *third* application should only **fill** data into the database. My application is a scraper, so there is no further input needed, i just need to start the application on a server.

Now the question: How would I typically set up the third application? Is there a VisualStudio-Project type that allows me to just create something like an "application server", so without controllers or views. I also need Entity-Framework, so my intention tells me to go with `ASP.NET` application, just remove controllers and add an `IHostedService`.

The reason I am asking is, that I want to host the application on an external provider's server and my provider only supports `ASP.NET` applications. In order to not run into any compatibility issues, I am asking for your best practices.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just because you need Entity Framework doesn't mean you have to use ASP.NET. The two have no bearing on each other. You can ASP.NET without Entity Framework, or Entity Framework without ASP.NET, or you can have both, or you can have either.

Comment: ASP.NET is all about handling HTTP requests and responding to them. If your app doesn't need to do that, then don't use ASP.NET. You can write an app to run as a [Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service), or you can write a console app and then execute it via Windows Task Scheduler, or use a tool like [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/). Or potentially even run it as an Azure Function or AWS Lambda or some other serverless framework. Research your options, pick which is most appropriate to your situation.

Comment: thanks @mason for your response, I will try this out.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to give you the answer (assuming you stick with said provider) - _I want to host the application on an external provider's server and my provider only supports ASP.NET applications_